# Transform complext text from RTF or PDF file into CSV

Tags: csv, pdf, transform, rtf

we are migrating from an older personnel accounting software to a new one and the only way to export the existing employees is via either RTF or PDF. They are not in lists but come formated like this (RTF example opened in Notepad++):

```
Employee No.    :       1                                       Date of Birth            :  28.05.1943\line
                                                                Gender                   :           1\line
Family Name     :  Korsig                                       Family status            :           1\line
First Name      :  Julia                                        Retired                  :           9\line
...
...
```

The same layout is the case for the PDF file.
There are about 3-4 pages per employee with over 120 employees in total (PDF file with 463 pages).

When talking to the vendor of the older personnel accounting software they state that migrations are usually done manually and that there are no export tools.

The new personnel accounting software vendor expects us to provide the data in an XLS spreadsheet i.e. it would be great if we can manage to transform the RTF or PDF data into CSV.

So we basically have three options:
1. Copy everything manually
2. Transform from RTF: Here I have looked around and Python seems to be a good choice
3. Transform from PDF: Here I thought of trying out iText in Java

What would be your advice on how to best solve this?
Time is also limited since we should have this ready in the next 4 days.

Comment: Welcome! Are you looking for an automated ad hoc software solution (that would lead to you using StackOverflow as a "free coding service" -which is against this site's rules-) or are you looking for general suggestion on how to solve this problem in a "stupid but not too stupid" way that would be faster?

Comment: sorry, no I meant not to exploit anyone here, just wanted to get some informed and experienced advice on which programming language, RTF vs. PDF approach would perhaps be best to take